# ios localization issue for library

Tags: ios, localization, bundle, nslocale

I am trying to develop a custom control and plan to publish it using github with a drag&drop installation.
To support localized strings i created a myControl.bundle directory with en.lproj and de.lproj folders inside. Each folder contains a myControl.strings with language specific content.

In the code I defined a macro like this:

```
#define myLocalizedString(key) \
NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(key, @"myControl", [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myControl.bundle"]], nil)
```

I then use

```
myLocalizedString(@"WHATEVER_TITLE");
```

In xcode I edited the Schemes to "Application Language" German and "Application Region" Germany. When I run it in the Simulator it works like a charm and displays a german user interface.

When I run it on the device, that is set to german language and german region, it shows me an english user interface.

The following code

```
NSString *language1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] firstObject];
    NSString *language2 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] lastObject];
    NSString *language3 = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",language1, language2, language3);
```

gives me this output:

```
en en de
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**edit:

The following code

```
NSString *language1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations] firstObject];
    NSString *language2 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations] lastObject];
    NSString *language3 = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@",language1, language2, language3);
```

gives me this output:

```
Base en de
```

Comment: Nevermind, i got it to work. The Base output in my last edit gave me a hint in the right direction.